# gpedit locked myself out Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, gpedit

To allow endpoint users execute only certain EXE files, I enabled *Run only specified Windows Applications* and fill whitelist with THOSE applications. To avoid locking myself out I added `gpedit.msc` and `cmd.exe` to whitelist BIG mistake, Now have no access to `gpedit.msc` not even from cmd.

---

**Note**: I have searched this issue and one of the possible solutions is `RD /s /Q` at cmd BUT its a Windows 7 solution, will this work on Windows 10.

Comment: That `rd /s /q` **deletes files** named "at" or "cmd"; it doesn't look even close to a solution.

Comment: related : http://serverfault.com/questions/380459/locked-myself-out-of-group-policy-editor

Comment: [Login into the default Administrator user then modify the registry](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/257189-applications-run-only-specified-programs-windows.html) and reverse your actions.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty old, but just ran into the issue and haven't seen the solution that worked for me posted.

**tldr:** You can modify the policy of the affected PC from another PC on the network through mmc snap-in - GPO Editor - point it to the affected PC.

Assuming the computer is in a domain & accessible from another PC -
Run mmc.exe elsewhere (I'd presume an admin workstation would be required) -> add snap-in -> Group Policy Object Editor -> Add.
In the Select Group Policy Object wizard that appears, hit Browse to change the Group Policy Object -> Another Computer -> Browse -> affected PC's name -> Check Names to verify -> Ok -> Ok -> Finish -> Ok.

This brought in the policy of the affected PC and I was able to modify/fix accordingly.

Comment: It important to note that MMC.EXE is the program that runs GPEdit.msc which is a MMC snapin.

Answer (score 0):

tldr: You can modify the policy of the affected PC from another PC on the network through mmc snap-in - GPO Editor - point it to the affected PC.

Assuming the computer is in a domain & accessible from another PC - Run mmc.exe elsewhere (I'd presume an admin workstation would be required) -> add snap-in -> Group Policy Object Editor -> Add.
In the Select Group Policy Object wizard that appears, hit Browse to change the Group Policy Object -> Another Computer -> Browse -> affected PC's name -> Check Names to verify -> Ok -> Ok -> Finish -> Ok

I tried, it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can just copy, c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe to for example c:\temp\ rename it to the same name app that you allow to run. For example you allow notepad.exe then rename it to notepad.exe. Once you rename, run the new name of cmd.exe as Administrator. Once open run MMC.exe, then you can reopen your gpedit.msc and disable the "Locked myself out of Group Policy Editor"